# Input range as a concatenation

Tags: google-sheets

I want to put this

```
="'Other Sheet'!C"&D5
```

(where D5 = 1432)

in a cell and get the actual value the formula refers to rather than the formula as a string (current result).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=INDIRECT("'Other Sheet'!C"&D5,TRUE)
```